# OpenFeign client doesn't apply "Content-Type" header value: 415 in response

Tags: java, http-headers, http-delete, feign, openfeign

I want to perform DELETE using feign:

```
public static <T> T createClient(Class<T> type) {
    return Feign.builder()
            .client(new OkHttpClient())
            .encoder(new GsonEncoder())
            .decoder(new CustomGsonDecoder())
            .logger(new Slf4jLogger(type))
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL)
            .target(type, url);
}
```

Method from ConsumersClient interface:

```
@RequestLine("DELETE /consumers/{id}")
@Headers({"Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer {token}"})
Response deleteConsumerById(@Param("token") String token, @Param("id") String id);
```

And when I do:

```
CLIENT = createClient(ConsumersClient.class);
CLIENT.deleteConsumerById(token, id)
```

And I got

```
{"statusCode":415,"error":"{\"timestamp\":\"2020-02-27T08:09:33.634Z\",\"status\":415,\"error\":\"Unsupported Media Type\",\"message\":\"Content type '' not supported\",\"path\":\"/consumers/id\"}"}
```

Since the message is: ""Content type '' not supported" I assume that Feign doesn't apply Content-Type value to its headers.

**PLEASE NOTE:** Same request via Postman returns 200 with the same parameters. So the service is working as expected.

Logback says the headers are included:

```
11:09:32.660 [main] DEBUG ConsumersClient - [ConsumersClient#deleteConsumerById] ---> DELETE https://hereGoesMyURL/consumers/id HTTP/1.1
11:09:32.663 [main] DEBUG ConsumersClient - [ConsumersClient#deleteConsumerById] Content-Type: application/json
11:09:32.663 [main] DEBUG ConsumersClient - [ConsumersClient#deleteConsumerById] Authorization: Bearer hereGoesTheToken
11:09:32.664 [main] DEBUG ConsumersClient - [ConsumersClient#deleteConsumerById] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

Please help to figure out what's wrong with my code.

Comment: How do you use this feign client?

Comment: @Arthurofos I build client with Feign.builder() and create requests using interface with delete method from the code above

Comment: Can you format your code well?

Comment: @Arthurofos Formatting in comments is hard... 

`Feign.builder()
.client(new OkHttpClient())
.encoder(new GsonEncoder()).decoder(new CustomGsonDecoder()).logger(new Slf4jLogger(type)).logLevel(Logger.Level.FULL).target(type, url);`

Comment: @Arthurofos It's seems like there's no way to post code in comments other than inline style

Comment: you can modify your question

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been discussed here:
https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/391

Since there's no defined semantics for DELETE with a body Feign is stripping the content-type header on this type of requests.